# 3rd party controls for pdf conversion and pdf viewer in Sharepoint

Tags: .net, sharepoint, pdf

Hi all
    i want to show the documents stored in the sharepoint libraries in the seperate window in pdf format without using another pdf softwares(like acrobat reader).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using a two step process.

First of all you need a PDF Converter for SharePoint such as [this one](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx). It supports many different formats, comes with a SharePoint GUI, full support for workflows, watermarking, PDF Security and a friendly web services interface as well.

You then need a [Flash](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sugexp=nspc&xhr=t&q=flash+based+pdf+viewer&cp=0&pf=p&sclient=psy&site=webhp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=f&oq=flash+based+pdf+vi&pbx=1&fp=ba7fef54647adf37&ion=1) or [Silverlight based PDF Viewer](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sugexp=nspc&xhr=t&q=silverlight+pdf+viewer&cp=2&pf=p&sclient=psy&site=webhp&aq=0c&aqi=&aql=f&oq=si+pdf+viewer&pbx=1&fp=ba7fef54647adf37&ion=1) to display the converted  document.

Please note that the PDF Converter is a product I have worked on, so consider me biased. Having said that, it is a great product, actively developed, with many happy customers

Comment: Ya i have downloaded and installed Muhimbi. For the pdf conversion its working fine. Can you have any idea about how to **display the pdf file content in a Silverlight based PDF Viewer**.

Comment: See the links in my reply for a Silverlight based PDf Viewer.

Comment: Ya i have seen the links. Is there any way to design our own way to view pdf files in silverlight with or without using 3rd party developer free OEM dlls.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Vizit SP (http://www.atalasoft.com/products/vizit), it does exactly what you need.